# Migrate select contacts into G Suite

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-workspace-for-business

I want to migrate SOME of my contacts from my gmail.com account into my new G Suite account. All the instructions I have read seem to import ALL of my contacts.

Perhaps something that would export to a text file that I can edit with a text editor, then import into G Suite.

What is a good way to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can export your Gmail contacts to a CSV file, edit it, and upload it: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1069522?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

These instructions work on MacOSX and Linux.

These instructions import the contacts into the company contact list so that all employees can see the contacts.  Hence the importance of the step to prune the contacts.  [EDIT: Turns out this did not import them into the company directory]

Here are the steps I did:

1. Open the source gmail account.
2. open contacts from the GMail/Contacts/tasks selection in upper left of screen.
3. Select `More v` menu item.
4. Select `Export...` item.
5. Choose `All Contacts`
6. Choose `Google CSV` format
7. Click `Export`
8. Expect a `google.csv` file to download.
9. Run this command

   iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 google.csv |grep -e "^Name" -e "@1.example.com" -e "@2.example.com" >googleimport.csv
10. open googleimport.csv in my favorite ext editor and prune further.
11. Login into target g-suite account.
12. Click the 9 squares menu on the upper right.
13. Click the `Contacts` icon.
14. Click the `More v` menu item.
15. Choose `Import...`
16. Choose the pruned csv file.
17. Choose `Import`
18. Expect contacts to populate after a minute two.  there was a short pause before phone numbers appeared on the contacts.